# How to add a custom block to WordPress Gutenberg blocks?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to create a new custom block for Gutenberg, is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. I recommend that you use a starter kit like [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) for creating Gutenberg blocks.

> ⚡️ Quick Overview

Run step #1 and #2 quickly in one go — Run inside local WP install E.g. /wp.local/wp-content/plugins/ directory.

```
npx create-guten-block my-block
cd my-block
npm start
```

Read all the details here on the [readme →](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block)

Comment: As a piece of information for the starter kit mentioned, installing it on node version v14.17.0 works fine. But other versions, it is recorded to have bugs and the install command does not complete. (Just a piece of information, no loss in trying)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Check out the [gutenberg handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/). You can find plenty of examples there like this one here:

```
// init.php
function gutenberg_boilerplate_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
        plugins_url( 'step-01/block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element' )
    );

    register_block_type( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5/hello-world-step-01', array(
        'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_boilerplate_block' );


// block.js:
var el = wp.element.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    blockStyle = { backgroundColor: '#900', color: '#fff', padding: '20px' };

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5/hello-world-step-01', {
    title: 'Hello World (Step 1)',

    icon: 'universal-access-alt',

    category: 'layout',

    edit: function() {
        return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello editor.' );
    },

    save: function() {
        return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello saved content.' );
    },
} );
```